# jQuery not recognizing selectors created by the .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic content box. When I click one button, the box's content changes with .html(). When I click another, the content changes again.

This is fine, but anything created within this box doesn't seem to be selectable.

So for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    boxContent1 = "<div class='studySelector'></div>";

    $("#caseStudy").on('click',function(){
        $("#botBox").hide().html(caseStudy).fadeIn(1000);
    });

});
```

in this case, the content of #botBox changes just fine. However, when I try to interact with it

```
$(".studySelector").on('click',function(){
    alert("testing!");
});
```

nothing happens. Why is this happening?

Comment: Use event delegation `$('#botBox').on('click', '.studySelector', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as you dynamically create nodes in the dom after rendering:

```
$('#botBox').on('click', '.studySelector',function(){
    alert("testing!");
});
```

should be working.